# Can I uninstall touchpad driver permanently?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, thinkpad, trackpoint

Can I uninstall the ELAN input device driver permanently?
I tried the **Uninstall Device** button and put a check on **Delete the driver software for this device**, but it still reinstalls it after I reboot the computer.
Also want to know Can I remove the **ThinkPad** tab on Mouse Properties?
I want my trackpoint(on touchpad unit) working as Microsoft's default behavior.

[image: touchpad]

[image: thinkpad]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

1.download your touchpad driver on Lenovo page
2.Install it, and open the folder that it was installed
3.find un_inst file and excute it
4.reboot your computer

Touchpad driver will be replaced with Microsoft default one and ThinkPad tab should be gone.